# Can I travel by road, from Greece to Italy, with only my Greek identity card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, montenegro, bosnia, eu-id-card

I will take a trip to Italy by road this September, and as my passport has expired and needs to be renewed, I only use my ID card to travel by plane, but can I use it for road trip also? I will travel from Greece, through to Albania (no problems with the ID), then Montenegro, Bosnia, Croatia, Slovenia and then Italy! Do you think they will not accept my ID card in any of these countries' borders?

Comment: Is this a "new" Greek ID card with latin characters or an "old" one with Greek characters only? You are fine with the former, but may have problems with the latter.

Answer (score 4):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_document#Greece), you should be fine for all eu member states.
Leaving bosnia and montenegro an uncertainty. [montenegro](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Montenegro) seems to accept eu id cards, so does [Bosnia](http://www.bhembassy.be/CI/5.html)

It seems that you can travel with you id only.

Answer (score 1):

All countries accept Greek ID cards, so you'll be perfectly fine.

Slovenia and Croatia are EU countries, and so have to accept it.

[Bosnia](http://www.mvp.gov.ba/konzularne_informacije/vize/Default.aspx) has accepted EU ID cards since September 2002, and [Montenegro](http://www.mvpei.gov.me/en/sections/consular-affairs/visa-regimes-for-foreign-citizens/greece) since June 2004